# Color text in a comboBox based on a condition

Tags: c#, combobox

I have the following code that populates a comboBox. Items coming from the database will have a boolean set to either true or false. If the boolean is set to true, I want to color those items red. My code that binds the comboBoxes looks like

```
            if (HasCoded) {
            listAnestheticMeds= new List<AnesthMedsInventory>();
            listAnestheticMeds = AnesthMeds.CreateObject();
            for (int i = 0; i < listAnestheticMeds.Count; i++) {
                if (listAnestheticMeds[i].Hidden == false && listAnestheticMeds[i].IsEmergencyMed) {
                    this.comboAnesthMed.Items.Add(listAnestheticMeds[i].AnesthMedName.ToString());

                }
            }
        }
```

with another loop that adds items to the comboBox if the condition is false (omitted for brevity). From what I've read I need to set the DrawMode to OwnerDrawVariable but am not sure how to write the code in the _DrawItemEvent handler to work with my code block.

Answer (score 0):

OK Solved.

Here's the full solution:

```
        private void comboAnesthMed_MeasureItem(object sender,
        System.Windows.Forms.MeasureItemEventArgs e) {
        e.ItemHeight = 12;
        e.ItemWidth = 160;
    }

    private void comboAnesthMed_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e) {
        // Draw the background 
        e.DrawBackground();
        // Determine the forecolor based on whether or not the item is selected    
        HasCoded = Convert.ToBoolean(AnestheticRecords.GetCodeStatus(anestheticRecordNum));
        if (HasCoded) {
            listAnestheticMeds = new List<AnesthMedsInventory>();
            listAnestheticMeds = AnesthMeds.CreateObject();
            for (int i = 0; i < listAnestheticMeds.Count; i++) {
                IsEmergencyMed = new string[listAnestheticMeds.Count];
                if (listAnestheticMeds[i].Hidden == false && listAnestheticMeds[i].IsEmergencyMed) {
                    if (comboAnesthMed.Items[e.Index].ToString() == listAnestheticMeds[i].AnesthMedName.ToString()) {
                        brush = Brushes.Red;
                    }
                }
                if (listAnestheticMeds[i].Hidden == false &! listAnestheticMeds[i].IsEmergencyMed) {
                    if (comboAnesthMed.Items[e.Index].ToString() == listAnestheticMeds[i].AnesthMedName.ToString()) {
                        brush = Brushes.Black;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        // Draw the text    
        e.Graphics.DrawString(comboAnesthMed.Items[e.Index].ToString(), ((Control)sender).Font, brush, e.Bounds.X, e.Bounds.Y) ;
    }
```